# How to use a protocol to SKPSMTPMessageDelegate in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I'm using the `SKPSMTPMessage` to send mails, but when I add functions I need `SKPSMTPMessageDelegate`. I add this:

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController,   SKPSMTPMessageDelegate
```

but I get the error: Type 'ViewController" does not conform to protocol '`SKPSMTPMessageDelegete`'

An i don't know how to add this, because what need I write into @objc protocol ??

```
 @objc protocol  SKPSMTPMessageDelegate{
//code here?
 }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting a message about not conforming to `SKPSMTPMessageDelegate`, that doesn't mean you have to define the protocol. It means that the protocol is already defined (in `SKPSMTPMessage.h`) and that you've failed to implement `messageSent` and/or `messageFailed`. Make sure you implement both of those functions in your `ViewController` class:

```
func messageSent(message: SKPSMTPMessage!) {
    <#code#>
}

func messageFailed(message: SKPSMTPMessage!, error: NSError!) {
    <#code#>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3:**

```
    func messageSent(_ message: SKPSMTPMessage!) {

    }

    func messageFailed(_ message: SKPSMTPMessage!, error: Error!) {

    }
```